# xml representation of 2d matrix

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to find best representation of 2d-matrix in xml (with xsd schema). I saw a lot of representation like [this](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xmldev/200209/post40810.html) or [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_xml_yaml_persistence.html). Nevertheless, I can not choose the best option. Please advise me. Maybe there are any recommendations or standarts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is strongly dependend on exact purpose you need it for (e.g. simple selects of cells or columns in xslt, possibility to express span cell or rows, etc.).

The most common (IMO) is the solution described in your first link (it is similar to HTML tables). In my point of view it is useful to define some attribute with number of actual row of cell - just to make selection or reference more simple and also to be able to skip some cell or rows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:complexType name="cell_type">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="cellNo" type="xs:int" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="row_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Cell" type="cell_type" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="rowNo" type="xs:int" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Matrix">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Row" type="row_type" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:unique name="cellNoKey">
                        <xs:selector xpath="Cell" />
                        <xs:field xpath="@cellNo" />
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="rowNoKey">
            <xs:selector xpath="Row" />
            <xs:field xpath="@rowNo" />
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```